# Changing VBA code on Access 2016 report cause no pages to be printed

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

First if this a duplicate (that I can't find) I am sorry.

I have been searching for more then a week for an answer to this.

I have an Access 2003 Database that has a Front End (fe) a Back End (be) and a third db that holds the data. I know this seems weird but its a German built Access DB from way back.

Here is the problem. From the main data entry form there is a print button that calls another form. This second form has two text boxes that have a starting and ending order number fields. The starting number is passed from the main form.

There is a another print button on the second form that when clicked creates and prints a report. The report is where the problem is. If I add ANY vba code to the report, even just making a label visible, the report prints nothing. The printer dialog window appears like it is sending something but nothing is ever printed.

I have tried sending to a PDF but nothing. Now if I go to the report code and comment out the line to that makes the label visible the report prints fine. I have been working with DB's along time and I have never seen anything like this, Hell I have never even heard of anything like this.

Be warned that this code has a lot of German in it.

```
    Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Detailbereich_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer) 'Detail Area Format

'On Error GoTo Err_Detailbereich_Format

Dim dbDatenbank As Database
Dim dtPPSDaten, dtEinfassung, dtToleranz As Recordset
Dim sql As String


Dim T                   As Double       'Angepasste Tragstablänge
                                            'Adjusted Bearing Bar rod-length

Dim TA                  As Double       'Anzahl Tragstäbe
                                            'Number of Bearing Bar rods

Dim TA_Anzahl           As String       'Zwischenfeld für Tragstabanzahlberechnung ohne Rundung
                                            'Inter-field for Bearing Bar-number-calculation of curve

Dim FA_Anzahl           As String       'Zwischenfeld für Füllstabanzahlberechnung ohne Rundung
                                            'Inter-field for Cross Bar-number-calculation of curve

Dim Komma               As Byte         'Zwischenfeld zum Filtern der Dezimalzalen
                                            'Inter-field to filtering the decimal zal en

Dim FA                  As Double       'Füllstabanzahl
                                            'Cross Bar-number

Dim TEM                 As Double       'Tragstabendmasche
                                            'Bearing Bar Mesh

Dim FEM                 As Double       'Füllstabendmasche
                                            'Cross Bar Mesh

Dim ZFEM                As Double       'Zusatzwert Füllstabendmasche
                                            'Addition-value Cross Bar Mesh

Dim MEMT                As Double       'Mindestendmasche Tragstab (Toleranz)
                                            'Bearing Bar Mesh Tolerance

Dim MEMF                As Double       'Mindestendmasche Füllstab (Toleranz)
                                            'Cross Bar Mesh Tolerance

Dim Rand1_2             As Double       'Technologischer Abzug Rand1+2 (Toleranz)
                                            'Technological departure edge

Dim Rand3_4             As Double       'Technologischer Abzug Rand3+4 (Toleranz)
                                            'Technological departure edge

Dim Einfassungsdicke    As Single       '(aus Tabelle: Einfassung)
                                            'Banding Thickness

Dim Einfassungsmaterial As String * 35  '(aus Tabelle: Einfassung)
                                            'Banding Material

Dim Toleranz_Füllstab   As Single       '(aus Tabelle: Toleranz)
                                            'Cross Bar Tolerance

Dim Toleranz_Tragstab   As Single       '(aus Tabelle: Toleranz)
                                            'Bearing Bar Tolerance

Dim ProdAuftrag         As Long         '(aus Tabelle: PPS_Daten_IN)

Dim PositionsNr         As String * 3   'Zwischenfeld zum auffüllen der PositionsNr mit Nullen
                                            'Position Number with zeros

Dim Auffüllen           As Long         'Zwischenfeld
Dim Barcode_ProdAuftrag As String * 9   'Zwischenfeld
Dim Artikeltyp          As Byte         'Zwischenfeld
Dim Durchlauf           As Byte         'Zwischenfeld

Dim Inch                As Single
Dim Feet                As Single

Feet = 10.764
Inch = 25.4
ZFEM = 0
Komma = 0
Durchlauf = 1

'Einfassungsbereich sichtbar machen, evtl. durch Mattenfertigung ausgeblendet
' Border-area visible does, evtl. through mat-production faded out

[Report_Fertigungszettel]![Jahreszahl].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![AuftragsNr].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![Kunde].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![txtEinfassung_Einfassung].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![Position].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![Rostbezeichnung].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![Bestellmenge].Visible = True


'********************************************************************
'Unterschiedliche Einblendung zwischen SP- und P-Rosten
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![lbl_ef_lob1].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![lbl_ef_lob2].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![lbl_ef_lob3].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![Einfassungslänge].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![EinfassungslängeTS].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![EinfassungslängeFS].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![Einfassungslänge_Inch].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![EinfassungslängeTS_Inch].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![EinfassungslängeFS_Inch].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![MaterialbezeichnungTS].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![MaterialbezeichnungEF2].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![lbl_ef_quantity1].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![lbl_ef_quantity2].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![lbl_ef_quantity3].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![Einfassungsanzahl].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![EinfassungsanzahlTS].Visible = True
[Report_Fertigungszettel]![EinfassungsanzahlFS].Visible = True
'********************************************************************

Set dbDatenbank = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)

'Technologische Werte aus Tabelle Toleranz übernehmen
' Update Tolerance Information
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Toleranz WHERE Toleranz = " & Toleranz
    Set dtToleranz = dbDatenbank.OpenRecordset(sql)

        MEMT = dtToleranz![Tol_Tragstab_Min_Masche] 'Bearing Bar Mesh

        MEMF = dtToleranz![Tol_Füllstab_Min_Masche] 'Cross Bar Mesh

        Rand1_2 = dtToleranz![Tol_Rand1+2] 'Banding Thickness for sides 1 & 2
        Rand3_4 = dtToleranz![Tol_Rand3+4] 'Banding Thinckness for sides 3 & 4
        Toleranz_Füllstab = dtToleranz![Tol_Füllstab] 'Cross Bar
        Toleranz_Tragstab = dtToleranz![Tol_Tragstab] 'Bearing Bar

    dtToleranz.Close

'Einfassungswerte aus Tabelle Einfassung übernehmen
' Update Banding Information
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Einfassung WHERE Einfassung = " & Einfassung
    Set dtEinfassung = dbDatenbank.OpenRecordset(sql)

        Einfassungsdicke = dtEinfassung![Einf_Dicke] '
        Einfassungsmaterial = dtEinfassung![Einf_Materialbezeichnung]
        txtEinfassung_Einfassung.Value = dtEinfassung![Einf_Bezeichnung]
        txtFüllstab_Einfassung = dtEinfassung![Einf_Bezeichnung]
        txtTragstab_Einfassung = dtEinfassung![Einf_Bezeichnung]

        If Einfassungsdicke = 0 Then
        txt_hide_banding.Visible = True
        txt_hide_banding = "NO BANDING"
        End If

    dtEinfassung.Close

'Unterscheidung Artikeltyp/Rosttyp
' Case statement based on the part type, keyed off of the first digit of the machine part number
    Artikeltyp = Left(Rosttyp, 1)
    Select Case Artikeltyp

    Case "1"

        lblPW1.Visible = False
        lblPW2.Visible = True
        lblPW3.Visible = True


    'Berechnung P-Rost
    ' Calc BB MFG Length
    Tragstablänge = Tragstab - Einfassungsdicke - Einfassungsdicke - Toleranz_Tragstab
    Tragstablänge_Inch = Tragstablänge / Inch

    ' Calc CB MFG Length
    Füllstablänge = Füllstab - Toleranz_Füllstab
    Füllstablänge_Inch = Füllstablänge / Inch


  '  MaterialbezeichnungEF1 = Einfassungsmaterial
    MaterialbezeichnungEF2 = Einfassungsmaterial

    ' Calc CB Banding Length
    EinfassungslängeFS = Füllstab - Rand3_4
    EinfassungslängeFS_Inch = EinfassungslängeFS / Inch

    ' Calc BB Banding Length
    EinfassungslängeTS = Tragstab - Rand1_2
    EinfassungslängeTS_Inch = EinfassungslängeTS / Inch

    ' Calc Total Banding Qty (Qty * 2)
    EinfassungsanzahlTS = Bestellmenge * 2
    EinfassungsanzahlFS = Bestellmenge * 2

    '******************************************************************
    'FIX
    ' Add Comments for LARGE BB pieces (over 1800mm)
   '     If (Tragstablänge > 1800) Or (Füllstablänge > 1800) Then

   '         lblcommentsBand = "OVER 1800mm, ENTER BANDING MANUALLY in 2 PIECES.  " & lblcommentsBand
    '    Else

           ' lblcommentsBand = Comments
    '    End If
    '*******************************************************************



    TA_Anzahl = Füllstab / Tragstabteiler
    Komma = InStr(1, TA_Anzahl, ".", vbTextCompare)
    If Komma <> 0 Then
        TA = CInt(Left(TA_Anzahl, (Komma - 1)))
    Else
        TA = CInt(TA_Anzahl)
    End If

    Komma = 0

    FA_Anzahl = Tragstab / Füllstabteiler
    Komma = InStr(1, FA_Anzahl, ".", vbTextCompare)
    If Komma <> 0 Then
        FA = CInt(Left(FA_Anzahl, (Komma - 1)))
    Else
        FA = CInt(FA_Anzahl)

    End If

    TEM = (Tragstablänge - ((FA - 1) * Füllstabteiler)) / 2

    If TEM < MEMT Then
        FA = FA - 1
        TEM = (Tragstablänge - ((FA - 1) * Füllstabteiler)) / 2
        If TEM < MEMT Then
            FA = FA - 1
            TEM = (Tragstablänge - ((FA - 1) * Füllstabteiler)) / 2
        End If
    End If

    If TEM < ((Füllstabteiler / 2) + (Füllstabteiler * 0.05)) Then
        FA = FA - 1
        TEM = (Tragstablänge - ((FA - 1) * Füllstabteiler)) / 2
    End If

    FEM = (Füllstablänge - ((TA - 1) * Tragstabteiler)) / 2
    If FEM < MEMF Then
        TA = TA - 1
        FEM = (Füllstablänge - ((TA - 1) * Tragstabteiler)) / 2
        If FEM < MEMF Then
            TA = TA - 1
            FEM = (Füllstablänge - ((TA - 1) * Tragstabteiler)) / 2
        End If
    End If
    If FEM < ((Tragstabteiler / 2) + (Tragstabteiler * 0.05)) Then
        TA = TA - 1
        FEM = (Füllstablänge - ((TA - 1) * Tragstabteiler)) / 2
    End If

    Füllstabendmasche = Format(FEM, "###0.00")
    Füllstabendmasche_Inch = Füllstabendmasche / Inch
    füllstabendmasche_1 = Format(FEM, "###0.00")
    Füllstabendmasche_1_Inch = füllstabendmasche_1 / Inch



    '********************************************************************
    'Unterschiedliche Einblendung zwischen SP- und P-Rosten
    [Report_Fertigungszettel]![lbl_ef_lob1].Visible = False
    [Report_Fertigungszettel]![Einfassungslänge].Visible = False
    [Report_Fertigungszettel]![MaterialbezeichnungTS].Visible = False
    [Report_Fertigungszettel]![lbl_ef_quantity1].Visible = False
    [Report_Fertigungszettel]![Einfassungsanzahl].Visible = False
    'Ausblendung Stückzahlen bei T-Einfassung - Wunsch von Hr. Johann wegen Verwirrung bei Produktion Ohio

    If Toleranz = 1 Then
        [Report_Fertigungszettel]![EinfassungsanzahlTS].Visible = False
        [Report_Fertigungszettel]![EinfassungsanzahlFS].Visible = False
        [Report_Fertigungszettel]![lbl_ef_quantity2].Visible = False
        [Report_Fertigungszettel]![lbl_ef_quantity3].Visible = False
    End If


'********************************************************************
    Case 2

        lblPW1.Visible = True
        lblPW2.Visible = False
        lblPW3.Visible = False


    'Entscheidungskriterium für Mattenfertigung
    'Adjournment-criterion for mat-production
        If Einfassungsdicke = 0 Then
            T = Tragstab - Rand3_4
        Else
            T = Tragstab - (Tragstabdicke * 2) - Rand3_4
        End If

    'Berechnung SP-Rost
    'Calculation SP-Rost

        'TA-Anzahl = ((CrossBar - BearingBarThickness) / BearingBarPitch
        TA_Anzahl = ((Füllstab - Tragstabdicke) / Tragstabteiler)

        Komma = InStr(1, TA_Anzahl, ".", vbTextCompare)

        If Komma <> 0 Then
            'NumberOfBearingBars = CInt(Left(TA_Anzahl, (Komma - 1))) + 2
            TA = CInt(Left(TA_Anzahl, (Komma - 1))) + 2
        Else
            'NumberOfBearingBars = CInt(TA_Anzahl) + 2
            TA = CInt(TA_Anzahl) + 2
        End If

        'CrossBarNumber = MFG BearingBar Length \ CrossBarPitch
        FA = T \ Füllstabteiler

        'CrossBarNumber = (CrossBarNumber \ 2) * 2
        FA = (FA \ 2) * 2

        'BearingBarMesh = (MFGBearingBarLength - (CrossBarNumber-1)*CrossBarPitch)/2
        TEM = (T - (FA - 1) * Füllstabteiler) / 2

        'If BearingBarMesh >= (CrossBarPitch + BearingBarMeshTolerance) Then
        If TEM >= (Füllstabteiler + MEMT) Then
            'CrossBarNumber = CrosbarNumber + 2
            FA = FA + 2
            'BearingBarMesh = (MFBearingBarLength - (CrossBarNumber - 1) * CrossBarPitch) / 2
            TEM = (T - (FA - 1) * Füllstabteiler) / 2
        End If

        'If BearingBarMesh < BearingBarMeshTolerance then
        If TEM < MEMT Then
            'CrossBarNumber = CrossBarNumber - 2
            FA = FA - 2
            'BearingBarMesh = (MFGBearingBarLength - (CrossBarNumber - 1) * CrossBarPitch) /2
            TEM = (T - (FA - 1) * Füllstabteiler) / 2
        End If

        Select Case Tragstabteiler 'BearingBarPitch
            Case 30.15
                'CrossBarMesh = CrossBarLength - (NumberofBearingBars - 2) * BearingBarPitch - Side3&4 banding thickness - (2 * Bearing Bar Thickness)
                FEM = Füllstab - (TA - 2) * Tragstabteiler - Rand3_4 - (2 * Tragstabdicke)
                'If CrossBarMesh < 16.6 AND CrosbarMesh > = 1 then
                If FEM < 16.6 And FEM >= 1 Then
                    'CrossBarMesh = CrosbarMesh + 15.07
                    FEM = FEM + 15.07
                    'CrossBarMesh plus value = 15
                    ZFEM = 15.07
                End If

                'If CrossBarMesh < 1 then
                If FEM < 1 Then
                    'CrossBarMesh = CrossBarMesh + 30.15
                    FEM = FEM + 30.15
                    'NumberOfBearingBarRods = NumberOfBearingBarRods - 1
                    TA = TA - 1
                End If

            Case 30.16
                'CrossBarMesh = CrossBarLength - (NumberofBearingBars - 2) * BearingBarPitch - Side3&4 banding thickness - (2 * Bearing Bar Thickness)
                FEM = Füllstab - (TA - 2) * Tragstabteiler - Rand3_4 - (2 * Tragstabdicke)
                'If CrossBarMesh < 16.6 AND CrosbarMesh > = 1 then
                If FEM < 16.6 And FEM >= 1 Then
                    'CrossBarMesh = CrosbarMesh + 15.07
                    FEM = FEM + 15.07
                    'CrossBarMesh plus value = 15
                    ZFEM = 15.07
                End If

                'If CrossBarMesh < 1 then
                If FEM < 1 Then
                    'CrossBarMesh = CrossBarMesh + 30.15
                    FEM = FEM + 30.15
                    'NumberOfBearingBarRods = NumberOfBearingBarRods - 1
                    TA = TA - 1
                End If

        Case Else
                'CrossBarMesh = 9999
                FEM = 9999
                TA = TA - 1
        End Select


         ' Calc CB MFG Length
         'CrossBarLength = CrossBar + CrossBarTolerance
         Füllstablänge = Füllstab + Toleranz_Füllstab

         'CrosBarLength = CrossBarLength / 25.4
         Füllstablänge_Inch = Füllstablänge / Inch


         ' Calc BB MFG Length
         'BearingBarLength = (BearingBar - Side3&4BandThickness - (2 * BandingThickness)
         Tragstablänge = (Tragstab - Rand3_4 - (2 * Einfassungsdicke))
         Tragstablänge_Inch = Tragstablänge / Inch


         MaterialbezeichnungEF2 = Einfassungsmaterial
        ' Calc CB Banding Length
         EinfassungslängeFS = Füllstab - Rand3_4
         EinfassungslängeFS_Inch = EinfassungslängeFS / Inch

         ' Calc BB Banding Length
         EinfassungslängeTS = Tragstab - Rand1_2
         EinfassungslängeTS_Inch = EinfassungslängeTS / Inch

         ' Calc Total Banding Qty (Qty * 2)
         EinfassungsanzahlTS = Bestellmenge * 2
         EinfassungsanzahlFS = Bestellmenge * 2


        'INCH Anpassung nicht vergessen
         Füllstabendmasche = Format(FEM, "###0.00") '& " : " & Format(ZFEM, "###0.00")
         füllstabendmasche_1 = Format(FEM, "###0.00") '& " : " & Format(ZFEM, "###0.00")

         Füllstabendmasche_Inch = Format(FEM / Inch, "###0.00") & " : " & ZFEM
         Füllstabendmasche_1_Inch = Format(FEM / Inch, "###0.00") & " : " & ZFEM






        'Bei Mattenfertigung wird Einfassunsbereich nicht angedruckt
        If Einfassungsdicke = 0 Then
            [Report_Fertigungszettel]![Jahreszahl].Visible = False
            [Report_Fertigungszettel]![AuftragsNr].Visible = False
            [Report_Fertigungszettel]![Kunde].Visible = False
            [Report_Fertigungszettel]![txtEinfassung_Einfassung].Visible = False
            [Report_Fertigungszettel]![Position].Visible = False
            [Report_Fertigungszettel]![txtTragstab].Visible = False
            [Report_Fertigungszettel]![txtFüllstab].Visible = False
            [Report_Fertigungszettel]![Rostbezeichnung].Visible = False
            [Report_Fertigungszettel]![Bestellmenge].Visible = False
            [Report_Fertigungszettel]![Einfassungslänge].Visible = False
            [Report_Fertigungszettel]![Einfassungsanzahl].Visible = False
            [Report_Fertigungszettel]![MaterialbezeichnungTS].Visible = False
        Else
            Einfassungslänge = Füllstab
            Einfassungslänge_Inch = Einfassungslänge / Inch

            Einfassungsanzahl = Bestellmenge * 2
        End If

    Case Else
                FEM = 9999
                TEM = 9999
    End Select
'********************************************************************


    'Berichtsfelder zuweisen - Bereich Füllstab
        Füllstabanzahl = FA * Bestellmenge & " / " & FA

    'Berichtsfelder zuweisen - Bereich Tragstab
    'Report-fields assign - area filling-rod
        Tragstabanzahl = TA * Bestellmenge & " / " & TA
        Tragstabendmasche = Format(TEM, "###0.00")
        Tragstabendmasche_Inch = Tragstabendmasche / Inch
        Klinkung = FA

    'Zeichnungskästchen anzeigen
    'Show Drawing Boxes
        If Zeichnung = -1 Then
            lblZeichnungBearing = "Review Traveler / DWG"
            lblZeichnungCross = "Review Traveler / DWG"
            lblZeichnungBand = "Review Traveler / DWG"
        Else
            lblZeichnungBearing = ""
            lblZeichnungCross = ""
            lblZeichnungBand = ""
        End If

    'Barcode links ausfüllen
    'Fill Barcode Links
        If Len(Position) <> 3 Then
            Auffüllen = 3 - Len(Position)
            PositionsNr = String(Auffüllen, "0") & Position
        End If

'********************************************************************

'Daten Fertigungszettel in Datenbank PPS-Daten.mdb schreiben
'Write the records to the PPS-Daten-IN db
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [PPS-Daten-IN] where Projekt = " & AuftragsNr & " and Artikel = """ & Mark & """"
    Set dtPPSDaten = dbDatenbank.OpenRecordset(sql)

    If dtPPSDaten.RecordCount = 0 Then
                ' Get the Seq number

            Dim db As Database
            Dim rs, ros As Recordset
            Dim dbSQL, rosSQL As String

            Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)

            dbSQL = "SELECT SeqNum FROM [SEQNum] where ID = 1"
            Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(dbSQL)

           rosSQL = "SELECT HöheTS, DickeFS FROM Rostbezeichnung WHERE Rostbezeichnung = """ & Rostbezeichnung & """"
           Set ros = db.OpenRecordset(rosSQL)



                    With rs
                            .Edit
                            !SeqNum = !SeqNum + 1
                            .Update
                    End With

                    OpSeqBand.Caption = rs!SeqNum
                    OpSeqCB.Caption = rs!SeqNum
                    OpSeqBB.Caption = rs!SeqNum


            With dtPPSDaten
                    .AddNew
                    !Projekt = AuftragsNr
                    !Bez_Rost = Rostbezeichnung
                    !Artikel = Mark
                    !Arttext1 = rs!SeqNum
                    !Rost_TS = Tragstab
                    !Rost_FS = Füllstab
                    !Stück_S0 = Bestellmenge
                    !Bez_Komp_1 = Einfassungsmaterial
                    !Länge_1 = EinfassungslängeTS
                    !Länge_2 = EinfassungslängeTS
                    !Länge_3 = EinfassungslängeFS
                    !Länge_4 = EinfassungslängeFS
                    !Bez_Komp_5 = MaterialbezeichnungTS
                    !Länge_TS = Tragstablänge
                    !Endma_TS = Format(TEM, "###0.00")
                    !Stück_TS = TA
                    !Teilung_TS = Tragstabteiler
                    !Bez_Komp_6 = MaterialbezeichnungFS
                    !Länge_FS = Füllstablänge
                    !Endma_FS = Format(FEM, "###0.00")
                    !Stück_FS = FA
                    !Teilung_FS = Füllstabteiler
                    !Eintragsdatum = Forms![Fertigungskopf]![Datum]
                   !Höhe_TS = ros!HöheTS
                   !Stärke_FS = ros!DickeFS
                    ProdAuftrag = !Prodauftr

                    .Update
            End With
            dtPPSDaten.Close
            rs.Close

        Else
            ' The to take into account the looping issue.  When this is the 2nd time through on the same
            ' Mark #, then get the Machine # for the report

                dtPPSDaten.Close
                sql = "SELECT Prodauftr, Arttext1 FROM [PPS-Daten-IN] where Projekt = " & AuftragsNr & " and Artikel = """ & Mark & """"
                Set dtPPSDaten = dbDatenbank.OpenRecordset(sql)

                ProdAuftrag = dtPPSDaten.Prodauftr
                OpSeqBand.Caption = dtPPSDaten.Arttext1
                OpSeqCB.Caption = dtPPSDaten.Arttext1
                OpSeqBB.Caption = dtPPSDaten.Arttext1

                dtPPSDaten.Close



        End If



    'End If


'********************************************************************
'Barcode rechts ausfüllen (nachgelagert wegen Produktionsauftragsnummer aus Tabelle PPS-Daten-IN)
    If Len(Trim(ProdAuftrag)) <> 9 Then
        Auffüllen = 9 - Len(Trim(ProdAuftrag))
        Barcode_ProdAuftrag = String(Auffüllen, "0") & ProdAuftrag
        Barcode_PA_Edgebanding = "*" & Barcode_ProdAuftrag & "*"
        Barcode_PA_crossbar = "*" & Barcode_ProdAuftrag & "*"
        Barcode_PA_Bearingbar = "*" & Barcode_ProdAuftrag & "*"
    Else
        Barcode_PA_Edgebanding = "*" & Barcode_ProdAuftrag & "*"
        Barcode_PA_crossbar = "*" & Barcode_ProdAuftrag & "*"
        Barcode_PA_Bearingbar = "*" & Barcode_ProdAuftrag & "*"
    End If


'------------------------------------------------------------------
    Me.Label444.Visible
    Me.Label445.Visible


Exit_Detailbereich_Format:
    Exit Sub

Err_Detailbereich_Format:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Detailbereich_Format

End Sub
```

If you scroll to the very end you will see to lines that make labels 444 and 445 visible. If i comment this lines out, as they are the only ones I added, the report will work correctly.

Oh and it does not matter where the code is placed as the end result is always the same, no output.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening?? I have hit the wall on this one.

Thanks to any suggestions I can get.

Comment: You could try uncommenting the 'On Error GoTo Err_Detailbereich_Format line and see if an error is being generated.

Comment: Just tried that but nothing changed. It didn't throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for making a control visible is

```
Me.Label444.Visible = True
Me.Label445.Visible = True
```

The visible property is expecting a Boolean value so you have to set it to either true or false.  This might solve the problem.

Comment: Ok so that worked and the report printed. Why would the whole report not print because of those two lines and better yet why no errors when compiling? I don't get it.

Comment: Ok so I started to add the code I need line by line till I get to a line that causes the report to fail.

Comment: So what would be wrong with the following then

    Dim db1 as DAO.Database
    Dim rs1 as DAO.Recordset

    Set db1 = CurrentDb()

All above lines work fine. But the next one fails...
    Set rs1 = db1.OpenRecordset(sqlCmd)

sqlCmd is defined as the following:
    sqlCmd = "Select [orderNr], [mark], [bbqty], [bbed], [punches], [cbed], [cbqty] From [tblOverRide] Where [orderNr] = '" & ordNumber & "' [mark] = '" & mrkNumber & "'"

Comment: I don't know why it caused the report not to print and didn't cause an error.  That is strange behavior.

Regarding the new code, you need an AND operator between where clause conditions.

Comment: I figured that out. The Germans turned off the warnings in some hidden code so any errors would not be seen. Thanks